# How to get number of frags for every player in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have got a Table:

```
------------------------------------
id        player_id        frag_id
------------------------------------
1         111111           1
2         222222           2
3         333333           3
4         444444           4
5         555555           5
6         555555           6
7         555555           7
8         666666           8
```

So, every player can kill something, and every frag has an id.

How to get table, where i will have got number  of frags of every player

```
------------------------------------
id        player_id        count_of_frags
------------------------------------
1         111111           1
2         222222           1
3         333333           1
4         444444           1
5         555555           3
6         666666           1
```

Comment: That would appear to be the 'count of frags'

Answer (score 2):

Use a COUNT() and then GROUP BY player_id

```
SELECT player_id, COUNT(frag_id) AS count_of_frags
FROM `foo`
GROUP BY `player_id`
```

Comment: You should include `player_id` in the `SELECT` list.